# AWS SDK S3 calls, inside a forEach while updating the forEach array

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, promise, aws-sdk

First Im using the s3.listObject() method to get a list of objects inside a bucket.  That is a promise and I am sending the results over to another functions where I want to loop through the results and collect meta data on each object:

```
  S3.listObjects({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    MaxKeys: 10,
    Marker: marker,
  })
  .promise()
  .then(collectRedirects)
  .then(callback); // each object in my list should now all have a new property, the metatag
```

Inside the collectRedirects function, I need to iterate over the passed in results and then use another asynchronous function s3.getObject to get the metatags.  Something like:

```
collectRedirects(objects) {
    objects.forEach(function(e,i,a){
        a[i].foo = S3.getObject({
            Key: e.Key,
            Bucket: bucketName
          })
          .promise()
          .then(function(result){
            Promise.resolve( result.foo );
          });
      }); //end loop
   return objects;
}
```

However the loop is completing before the getObject method resolves. Whats my next step?

I tried to save the result of the getObject method to an array of promises and then running Promise.all, but that is just giving me an array of undefined values:

```
var promises = [];
objects.forEach(function(e,i,a){
  let p = S3.getObject({...})
  .promise().then(function(result){ 
    Promise.resolve( result.foo ); 
  });
  promises.push(p);
});
Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Don't use `forEach`+`push`, use `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not `return`ing the anything from the `function(result){  Promise.resolve( result.foo ); }`. It just creates a promise, then drops it and returns `undefined`.

You are looking for `function (result) { return result.foo; }`.

Altogether, you would write

```
collectRedirects(objects) {
  var promises = objects.map(function(e){
    return S3.getObject({
      Key: e.Key,
      Bucket: bucketName
    }).promise().then(function(result){
      return result.foo;
      // or alternatively (if you want to amend the original object)
      e.foo = result.foo;
      return e;
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
    console.log(values);
    return values;
  });
}
```